# Is it possible my raspberry pi to melt its plastic case at 55° degrees?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, case

I have simple question, since my raspberry is new and i don't know if its ok when its 100 % of the time at 55 degrees and basically my question is does my raspberry will melt the plastic case at this temperature?

Comment: No it won't. Period. The kind of plastic that Pi cases are made of melts at temperatures much greater that 55 C. Anyhow, if it could melt the case it would also melt its own board, which is made of plastic also.

Comment: PCBs are usually made of an epoxy-fiberglass composite which is considerablly more heat resistant than most plastics.

Answer (score 5):

**No.***
At 55°C, the raspberry pi cannot melt its case.
ABS plastic *begins* to soften at around 100°C.

Regarding the Pi being damaged, don't worry about it. Raspberry Pies throttle back their CPU speed if they reach 85°C.

*Actually there have been a few rare instances of a Pi [melting its case](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=264410) or getting ridiculously hot. This happens when the SD card or CPU short out due to abuse. (like trying to run it on 12v)

Comment: So , basically at 55°C its not problem ?

Comment: Absolutely! Not a problem at all. At 85°C, you start to lose performance, so it's a good idea to keep your Pi cooler than that.

Comment: I wonder if a pi will function while suspended in boiling distilled water? Limits are easy to find, bit has anyone tried "suck it and see"? We might get lucky.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, that is off-topic for this question. But **NO**, don't put a Pi in distilled water. The metal parts will quickly ionize the water, the conductivity of the water will increase until the Pi is shorted out. If you want to soak your Pi in something, use mineral oil.